# Is it possible to drag to down panel slider as real android system slider using xamarin forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, slider

I have followed slider thing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387524/is-it-possible-to-drag-to-down-panel-slider-using-xamarin-forms) but I want to implement real android slider like as mentioned in below an image drag to down.

same as(drag to down slide):

[same as(drag to down slide)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Yj8v.png)

Anyone have an idea please share here. I have lots of tried but did not a success.

@Lucas Zhang, have your idea?

Answer (score 0):

#### in xaml

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="White" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1">
   <!--  -->
   <StackLayout x:Name="bottomDrawer" BackgroundColor="Olive" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1.00,0.9,0.04" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
   <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureHandler" />
   </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

   <!-- put the content of panel slider here -->

   </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

#### in code behind

```
    double? layoutHeight;
    double layoutBoundsHeight;
    int direction;
    const double layoutPropHeightMax = 0.75;
    const double layoutPropHeightMin = 0.04;
    void PanGestureHandler(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        layoutHeight = layoutHeight ?? ((sender as StackLayout).Parent as AbsoluteLayout).Height;
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                layoutBoundsHeight = AbsoluteLayout.GetLayoutBounds(sender as StackLayout).Height;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                direction = e.TotalY < 0 ? 1 : -1;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                if (direction > 0)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {

                        var height = layoutPropHeightMin;

                        while (height < layoutPropHeightMax)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(2);
                            height += 0.04;

                            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomDrawer, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.00, 0.9, height));
                        }

                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {

                        var height = layoutPropHeightMax;

                        while (height > layoutPropHeightMin)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(2);
                            height -= 0.04;

                            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomDrawer, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.00, 0.9, height));
                        }

                    });
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

#### Note:

Since we had used `AbsoluteLayout` . You would better set the `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` instead of `HeightRequest` or `WidthRequest` when you want to add child control in the panel silder .

Comment: whenever we drag to down than can we dragging the "AbsoluteLayout " section?
Right now I'm able to slide only my content

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: Of course you can use `AbsoluteLayout` instead of   `StackLayout`.

Comment: thanks for giving an answer, it's great if please provide little code for this  if possible

Comment: okay, but I want to hide slider section once it complemented slider Right now work for me like as  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeT0u.png,
can you please help me with code if possible

Comment: They are different questions . You could create a new thread with more details .

Comment: Is my answer helpful ?