# How to load custom emojis to the keyboard?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, keyboard, custom-controls, emoji

We have a requirement that we need to show the custom emojis on the keyboard instead of the default ones. Is there any way to load custom emoji's to the keyboard in Xamarin.forms.

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible without creating your own keyboard, due to Android and iOS platform limitations.
You have to implement your own keyboard view including a few emojis as buttons and some control buttons. Add a TapGestureRecognizer to your image. When this Tapped event fires show your custom keyboard view.

Comment: Thank you @LucasZhang-MSFT. It'd be better if they provide such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to load custom emojis to the keyboard?

Unfortunately it is impossible due to Android and iOS platform limitations.

However , we could  implement our own keyboard view including a few emojis as buttons and some control buttons . Add a **TapGestureRecognizer** to your image. When this Tapped event fires show your custom keyboard view. 
For more details about how to show and hide the custom View , I had provided a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387524/is-it-possible-to-drag-to-down-panel-slider-using-xamarin-forms/59389590#59389590) , you could have a check :)